# Should the oven temperature be the same for smaller batch?

Tags: baking, bread, temperature

Im making the no knead ciabatta bread and it calls for 4 cups of flour but i used 2 cups. It says to throw it in a 425 degree F oven for 35-45 minutes but i did that before and it would cook quickly. before 30 min. Should it remain the same temperature or should i alter it?

Answer (score 7):

Keep the oven temperature the same, as a good hot oven is necessary for the loaf to 'spring' (ie inflate somewhat). Just reduce the cooking time accordingly.

Comment: Yep, it's chemistry. Without the heat, lots of things do not happen.